# Did Windows 10 just delete Windows.Old?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

When my desktop had Windows 7, I had a folder `Windows.Old` in `c:\` from a previous installation. I then upgraded to `Windows 10`, and I noticed that `Windows.Old` now has the backup from this last Windows installation.

In other words, Windows 10 backed up my Windows 7 installation in this Windows.Old. Does this mean that my previous Windows.Old is gone?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows.old is created when you upgrade to a new version of Windows.  The contents should be deleted after 30 days.  If you havent needed to roll back to the old version by then, Windows will delete the contents of this folder to free space.

I have seen Windows not delete the contents for some unknown reason.  I have seen it delete the contents, but not the folder.

So, if your upgrade was more than 30 days ago, more than likely you wouldnt be able roll back to Windows 7.

Comment: Regardless of the reason, when I upgraded to Windows 10 five days ago, there was a c:\Windows.Old with files. Did WIndows 10 re-create that folder?

Comment: @rbhatup - You didn't have Windows.old unless you recently upgraded to Windows 7 from Windows Vista or Windows 7 to Windows 8/8.1 it didn't exist before that.  Any Windows.Old otherwise woudl have existed if you had installed Windows 7 over itself.  Yes; it likely was wiped, since it wasn't suppose to be permanent storage.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Windows 10 backup the previous version of Windows in Windows.old folder. If you have any issue/problem after upgrading to the new version, you have 10 days to go back to the previous version.
After 10 days the Windows.old folder will be automatically deleted. So, you can't go back to the previous version.
However, you can manually delete Windows.old folder from disk cleanup tool.
[Source](https://otechworld.com/how-to-delete-windows-old/)